# Ui-grid with ui-router passing params

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, ui-grid

I am a beginner (idiot alert)

I am successfully using ui-grid except when they click on an icon in a row it's meant to take them to a new view... The view I'm in showing the ui-grid has a url of

```
  #/reports/tickets
```

I have $stateProvider set as follows:

```
 .state('reports.tickets.details', {
        url: '/details/:ticketNum',
        templateUrl: 'partials/ticketDetail.html',
        controller: 'ticketDetailController'
    })
```

The data is displayed in ui-grid and a function is called when they click on the icon on the row in the grid. The log looks great, the url displays as I'd expect.

```
$scope.ticketDetailView = function(row) {
      $log.info(row);
      $state.go('reports.tickets.details', {ticketNum: row.TicketNum});
};
```

In my debugging the url is changing to

```
#/reports/tickets/details/7875452697
```

Exactly as expected.

So what's wrong with my initial state routing because it's not displaying the templateUrl or engaging the controller. I know this is a stupid beginners error. I've not ever worked with params in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `reports.tickets` state template should have `ui-view` in it. So that the child state will get loaded inside that `ui-view`

Comment: Yes. I have nested ui-views... that solved it - thank you.